# Как создать кнопку в телеграмм-боте?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Я делаю Телеграмм бота в пайчарм через telebot: с помощью команду старт выводится приветствие и некоторые кнопки, а при нажатии на некоторую кнопку вылетает текст. Я хочу, чтобы вместе с этим текстом в конце появлялась кнопка "Вернуться в меню", и чтобы кнопка появлялась сама после текста без всяких команд и сообщений. Как это можно сделать&

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)  (Другая строка) def callback_query(callback):
**if callback.data == '17': ????????????????????**
    send_welcome(message)
if callback.data == '1':
    bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, '<b>Органическая химия</b> — раздел химии, в котором изучают соединения углерода, их строение, свойства.......

    **@bot.????????????**
    def send_welcom(message):
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button17 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Назад", callback_data='17')
        markup.add(button17)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Назад?', reply_markup=markup)
```